# Finding word pattern between key characters

Tags: python, regex

Trying to create regular expression that finds the key word within one long string and when the key word is not surrounded by an letter. If the string is surrounded by a dash or underscore as long as it is not surround by letter.  Only need to find one occurrence of the word, to consider match. Only care about finding it in one long string. Currently, I can't get it to go True for when the word has a '_' next to it. Any ideas for a better expression?

Edit- I found a case where I need it to be true and did not add it to the example.

```
import re

key_words = ['go', 'at', 'why', 'stop' ]

false_match = ['going_get_that', 'that_is_wstop', 'whysper','stoping_tat' ]

positive_match = ['go-around', 'go_at_going','stop-by_the_store', 'stop','something-stop', 'something_stop']
pattern = r"\b(%s)\b" % '|'.join(key_words)

for word in false_match + positive_match:
    if re.match(pattern,word):
         print True, word
    else:
         print False, word
```

Current Output:

```
False going_get_that
False that_is_wstop
False whysper
False stoping_tat
True go-around
False go_at_going
True stop-by_the_store
True stop
```

Edit - This needs to be True

```
  False something-stop
  False something_stop
```

Desired output:

```
    False going_get_that
    False that_is_wstop
    False whysper
    False stoping_tat
    True go-around
    True go_at_going
    True stop-by_the_store
    True stop
    True something-stop
    True something_stop
```

Comment: Can you show a sample input and desire output?

Comment: Everything in `false_match` shouldn't match, but everything in `positive_match` should.

Comment: Sorry I added the desire output and also added a case where I need it to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative look(ahead|behind)s:

```
import re

key_words = ['go', 'at', 'why', 'stop' ]

false_match = ['going_get_that', 'that_is_wstop', 'whysper','stoping_tat' ]

positive_match = ['go-around', 'go_at_going','stop-by_the_store', 'stop', 'something-stop', 'something_stop']
pattern = r"(?<![a-zA-Z])(%s)(?![a-zA-Z])" % '|'.join(key_words)

for word in false_match + positive_match:
    if re.search(pattern,word):
         print True, word
    else:
         print False, word
```

Comment: Sorry I found a case where it needs to be True. I added it to the example above.

Comment: Adapted the code. Just replaced `re.match` with `re.search`.

Comment: This is the right approach (+1). Also might be a good use case for `re.IGNORECASE`, which would further simplify the regex.

Comment: @FMc: Yes, but case could be relevant in the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is close , you can use the following pattern :

```
pattern = r"\b([a-zA-Z]+[-_])?(%s)([-_][a-zA-Z_-]+)?\b" % '|'.join(key_words)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XzsdyafvNa5uhmMk)

Comment: I think you forgot to substitute %s in your example?!

Comment: @user3590149 :) yes! fixed!

Comment: Sorry I found a case where it needs to be True. I added it to the example above.

Comment: @user3590149 If you want the whole of the string for example `stop-by_the_store` you dont need to use look-around at all! so the other answer are incorrect as thy have gave me down vote!

Comment: @vks after that i have gave a down vote your reputation decrease -1 :) , and about my answer how you say its incorrect? as i have gave a +1 already  and its exactly what that OP wants. i think your answers are incorrect as there is no need to use look-around

Comment: Did not get you about the reputation........i did not say your answer is incorrect...... i haven't read it in detail..........my answer is working !!!!!!!why is it incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem with `\b` is it considers `_` to be a part of `\w` .So it is not a word boundary.To negate that effect make your own character class.**

```
(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9]))(go|at|why|stop)(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oC3qA3/8

```
import re

key_words = ['go', 'at', 'why', 'stop' ]

false_match = ['going_get_that', 'that_is_wstop', 'whysper','stoping_tat' ]

positive_match = ['go-around', 'go_at_going','stop-by_the_store', 'stop']
pattern = r"(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9]))(%s)(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)" % '|'.join(key_words)

for word in false_match + positive_match:
    if re.findall(pattern,word):
         print True, word
    else:
         print False, word
```

Output:`False going_get_that
False that_is_wstop
False whysper
False stoping_tat
True go-around
True go_at_going
True stop-by_the_store
True stop`

Comment: Sorry I found a case where it needs to be True. I added it to the example above.

Comment: @user3590149 its already working correctly for those you have added

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the change to re.findall. Thanks.

Comment: @vks because you are using look-around and your pattern just match the `%s` !